# Responsive background image resolution

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having issues with background image scales and responsive design.

I have a simple header image background along with a content image background. The header image is supposed to merge seamlessly into the content. Both images have fine grain textures, so they need to be the same scale at all times.

The header background is in an `<img>` tag, while the content is a `background-image`, as it needs to utilise the repeat-y functionality for an unknown amount of content...

But you can see the grain difference between the scaled inline image, and the background:

[image: Header/Content Divide]

I'm aware of the `background-size` attribute, but this is not backwards compatible, and I'm unsure if it caters responsively.

**My CSS**:

```
#header{

    max-width:700px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;

}

#header img{

    max-width:700px;
    width:100%;

}

#content{

    max-width:700px;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;    // <-- for testing with no content
    margin:0 auto;

    background-image:url('../imgs/bg-main.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;

}
```

**The Relevant HTML**:

```
<section id="header">
    <img src="lib/imgs/bg-top.jpg"/>
</section>
<section id="content">
    <!-- content goes here !-->
</section>
```

Any help on a fix or some options would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider making the header image a transparent png? Leave out the light brown texture in the header image and set it as the background-image on an element that wraps #header and #content.

Otherwise, `background-size` will do what you want. Visitors on IE8 will not see the proper effect your going for, but that's not the worst thing in the world these days.

See: http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: Dang. I feared there wouldn't be any joy on this one. I always seem to find the limitations of HTML with every design I implement. While I was waiting I went ahead and got the `background-size` property working nicely, so I'm considering just giving the 'v' to IE8 and below. Or perhaps just removing the texture on the images. Have +1'd, and will wait an hour or so before giving you the answer. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Many of the limitations that I encounter have to do with legacy IE and it's lack of support for the newer CSS features. In 2013, I think it's okay to show visitors using IE8 a slightly less than perfect design. As long as the usability of the site isn't harmed, it's better to push ahead with newer features and support modern browsers.

Comment: Also, track visitors with Google Analytics and see what percentage of people are even using IE8 to view the site. You might be surprised at the low number (I hope).